# Combining an Ajax call into one script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm still in the learning process and would love to know how I can combine the two scripts below, my code is working well now but I want to minimize it and combine them.

Here are the two differences in the two scripts below:
`&$filter=substringof('Consumer Products',Line1)",`
`$("#boxWrap").append(`

```html
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url:  "/NewBusiness/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('CompletedSubmissionTiles')/Items?$select=EncodedAbsUrl,Title,Line1,Line2,Hyperlink,TargetWindow,DescriptionHTMLOption,Line1,Line2,Line3,Line4,Line5,Line6,Line7,Line8,TileOrder&$orderby=TileOrder asc,Title asc&$filter=substringof('Healthcare',Line1)",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function (data) {
    if (data.d.results) {
    var object = data.d.results;
    var TileDesc;
    var Line1var;
    var Line2var;
    var Line3var;
    var Line4var;
    var Line5var;
    var Line6var;
    var Line7var;
    var Line8var;
    var Line9var;
    var Line10var;

    for(var i = 0; i < object.length; i++)
    {
    
    if(object[i].DescriptionHTMLOption != null) { // Covers 'undefined' as well
        TileDesc = "<div class='TileDescr'>" + object[i].DescriptionHTMLOption + "</div>";
    } else {
        TileDesc = "";
    }
    
    if(object[i].Line1 != null) { // Covers 'undefined' as well
        Line1var = "<div class='Line1'>" + object[i].Line1 + "</div>";
    } else {
        Line1var = "";
    }
    
    $("#boxWrap").append("<div class='col-md-4 box' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal"+object[i].TileOrder+"' id='TileBox"+object[i].TileOrder+"'><div id='titleBox' class='titleBox'><h1>" + object[i].Title + "</h1><div style='width:250px; height: 130px;background-color: white; border: 1px solid lightgrey;'><img style='width: auto; height: inherit; padding-left: 10px;' src='" +  object[i].EncodedAbsUrl + "' alt='" + object[i].Title +"'/></div></div></div>");
    }
    }
    }         
    })    
});
</script>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url:  "/NewBusiness/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('CompletedSubmissionTiles')/Items?$select=EncodedAbsUrl,Title,Line1,Line2,Hyperlink,TargetWindow,DescriptionHTMLOption,Line1,Line2,Line3,Line4,Line5,Line6,Line7,Line8,TileOrder&$orderby=TileOrder asc,Title asc&$filter=substringof('Consumer Products',Line1)",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function (data) {
    if (data.d.results) {
    var object = data.d.results;
    var TileDesc;
    var Line1var;
    var Line2var;
    var Line3var;
    var Line4var;
    var Line5var;
    var Line6var;
    var Line7var;
    var Line8var;
    var Line9var;
    var Line10var;

    for(var i = 0; i < object.length; i++)
    {
    
    if(object[i].DescriptionHTMLOption != null) { // Covers 'undefined' as well
        TileDesc = "<div class='TileDescr'>" + object[i].DescriptionHTMLOption + "</div>";
    } else {
        TileDesc = "";
    }
    
    if(object[i].Line1 != null) { // Covers 'undefined' as well
        Line1var = "<div class='Line1'>" + object[i].Line1 + "</div>";
    } else {
        Line1var = "";
    }
    
    $("#boxWrap2").append("<div class='col-md-4 box' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal"+object[i].TileOrder+"' id='TileBox"+object[i].TileOrder+"'><div class='titleBox'><h1>" + object[i].Title + "</h1><div style='width:250px; height: 130px;background-color: white; border: 1px solid lightgrey;'><img style='width: auto; height: inherit; padding-left: 10px;' src='" +  object[i].EncodedAbsUrl + "' alt='" + object[i].Title +"'/></div></div></div>");
    }
    }
    }         
    }) 
});
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like both `ajax` calls do everything the same except for what element they append to, am I correct?

Comment: Correct, it just appends differently and filter's differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `filter` and `id` are the only variables here, you could create separate function which takes those 2 parameter and do the ajax call in it. Append the  `filter` to the end of URL. Use the `id` inside the selector`$(id).append` Then create an array of object with 2 properties. Call the generic ajax function for each item in the array:

```
function getDataFromAjax(filter, id) {
   $.ajax({
      // append "filter" to the end of url
      url: "/NewBusiness/_api/web/lists/....Title asc&$filter=" + filter,
      type: "GET",
      headers: {
         "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
      },
      success: function(data) {
         if (data.d.results) {
            var object = data.d.results;
            var TileDesc;
            // OTHER VARIABLES

            for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
               /*
                LOTS OF LOGIC
               */

               // get the dynamic id
               $("#" + id).append("<div class='col-md-4 box' and so on");
            }
         }
      }
   })
}

var array = [{
      filter: "substringof('Healthcare',Line1)",
      id: "boxWrap"
   },
   {
      filter: "substringof('Consumer Products',Line1)",
      id: "boxWrap2"
   }
]

array.forEach(i => getDataFromAjax(i.filter, i.id))
```

Comment: This is amazing help, but sadly it's not populating anything now, am I throwing the function into `<script type="text/JavaScript">`? Doesn't append anything but I'm so thankful for the help!

Comment: Yes the whole thing. Make sure the `url` is stripped off of the `filter` values. It should be `url: "/NewBusiness/_api/web/lists/<lots of values here>$orderby=TileOrder asc,Title asc&$filter=" + filter,` Notice that `substringof('Healthcare',Line1)` is removed and it will be supplied by the `filter` parameter to the function.

Comment: @Semir314 I have removed most of the code to make it clear what I'm doing.

Comment: Thanks so much! So it's being appended between here `<div class="container"><div class="col-md-12" id="boxWrap"></div></div>` - Do I just call the function after "BoxWrap"?

Comment: @Semir314 Please see my answer, it should do everything you need.

Comment: @Semir314 I don't understand. Basically I have made only 2 changes to your code. Removed the `substringof('Healthcare',Line1)` from the `url` and replaced it with string appending `+ filter`. Then replaced `$("#boxWrap").append` line with `$("#" + id).append`. Put the whole thing into a function and calling it twice. It should work

Comment: For some reason, the 'function' is not wanting to be called at all, just doesn't append anything.

Comment: @Semir314 Can you check the console for any errors? Maybe arrow syntax in the `forEach` is not supported in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do much,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        getConsumerProducts();
        getHealthcare();
    });

    function getConsumerProducts(){
        $.ajax({
            // your many many lines of code
            // ...
        )}
    }
    function getHealthcare(){
        $.ajax({
            // your many many lines of code
            // ...
        )}
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making this it's own function which takes in the element id which will receive the append as well as the filter so something like this:

```
function DoMyApiCalls(elementId, filter){
    .ajax({
        //Inside here append your parameters into your strings, 
        url: url:  "/NewBusiness/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('CompletedSubmissionTiles')/Items?$select=EncodedAbsUrl,Title,Line1,Line2,Hyperlink,TargetWindow,DescriptionHTMLOption,Line1,Line2,Line3,Line4,Line5,Line6,Line7,Line8,TileOrder&$orderby=TileOrder asc,Title asc&$filter=" + filter,
        type: "GET",
        //etc.
        success:function(data){
            //etc.
            //Append to passed in element id
            $('#' + elementId).append();
        }

    });


}
```

Then you can just call this function x number of times passing each filter and element id in to the function respectively. So then you could put this in the `document.ready`:

```
DoMyApiCalls("boxWrap", "substringof('Healthcare',Line1)");
DoMyApiCalls("boxWarp2", "substringof('Consumer Products',Line1)");
```